# SQL INSERT failed, I can't find the issue

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, insert

I'm trying to insert something into a SQL server (using c#) and when I try to it says it requires the (in the query) given parameter and that it can't find it while it is declared.

> "Additional information: The parameterized query '(@art varchar(8000),@oms varchar(8000),@rem varchar(8000),@artdk' expects the parameter '@art', which was not supplied."

I checked parameter amount, the database connection and I tried to use another insert command I have as reference but I couldn't get it to work. and I couldn't find the same sort of problem on the internet yet. if someone could help me, it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:
I changed the artnr.selectedvalue to artnr.text and that sort of got me some progress but now I get this error

UPDATE2:
seems that if I fill every box it tries to insert it works.. yet it does allow null in all database cell's so the issue has been found. just got to work out which one('s) cant have empty.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

it gives this error when I put in all numeric or all text

```
SqlCommand slinkoopadd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into ART (ART ,OMS ,REM ,ARTDK ,TYPE ,MAG ,PROGRAM ,EH1 ,LEV ,LTD ,INK ,KOR ,SGR ,EH2 ,EF ,VALUTA ,CRNI )
                                                   values (@art,@oms,@rem,@artdk,@type,@mag,@program,@eh1,@lev,@ltd,@ink,@kor,@sgr,@eh2,@ef,@valuta,@crni);", Connectie.connMEVO_ART);
        #region parameters
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@art", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.SelectedValue;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@oms", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopoms.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@rem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopopmerk.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@artdk", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopnummerlev.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkooparttype.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@mag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopmagazijnloc.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopinternopmerk.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@eh1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopeenheid.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@lev", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopstandleveran.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ltd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkooplevertijd.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ink", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopbrutoprijs.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@kor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopkorting.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@sgr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopserievoorraad.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@eh2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopgebruikeh.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ef", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textinkoopehfactor.Text;
        //slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;//perc. voor vracht
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@valuta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopvaluta.Text;
        slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@crni", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopcrni.Text;
        //slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;//extra kosten
        //slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;//bestelgrootte afroep
        //slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;//prognose jaarverbruik
        //slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;//levertijd nieuwe afr
        #endregion
        drART = slinkoopadd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Opgeslagen!");
        fillbox();
        while (drART.Read())
        { }
        slinkoopadd.Dispose();
```

Comment: for those willing to try and help me. i will still be searching online for something that could help me, and i will keep checking this page so if there is some information you need please just ask.

Comment: Have you checked that ` this.artnr.SelectedValue ` is set and has a meaningful value?

Comment: You don't use `ExecuteReader` with `INSERT` statement. Use `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute it. `ExecuteReader` returns some data.

Comment: im trying to use 1 panel for mutliple things so the textbox is used to select an item it has to display normaly but for the insert it is more used like a textbox. i have tried diffrent things like the .text and .selectedtext

and the ExecuteReader does work with it so could you tell me the real diffrence between them?

Comment: If `this.artnr.SelectedValue` is `null`, you must pass `DBNull.Value` instead - if that fails run a Profiler Trace and see exactly whats being dispatched

Comment: its suppost to get the item that someone typed in there as i clear the list before so it should insert the typed text.

Comment: I would breakpoint & double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed some small things in the query and i made sure some of the textboxes get a default value if it doesnt have anything in it so now it works. this is the current query that works.

```
if (tekstinkoopcrni.Text == "1") { } else if (tekstinkoopcrni.Text == "0") { } 
else { tekstinkoopcrni.Text = "0"; }
if (tekstinkoopkorting.Text == "") { tekstinkoopkorting.Text = "0"; }
if (tekstinkoopserievoorraad.Text == "") { tekstinkoopserievoorraad.Text = "0"; }
if (tekstinkoopstandleveran.Text == "") { tekstinkoopstandleveran.Text = "9999"; }
if (tekstinkooplevertijd.Text == "") { tekstinkooplevertijd.Text = "0"; }

SqlCommand slinkoopadd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into ART (ART ,OMS ,REM ,ARTDK ,TYPE ,
MAG ,PROGRAM ,EH1 ,INK ,KOR ,SGR ,EH2 ,EF ,VALUTA ,CRNI  ,LEV ,LTD )
values (@art,@oms,@rem,@artdk,@type,@mag,@program,@eh1,@ink,@kor,@sgr,@eh2,@ef,
@valuta,@crni, @lev,@ltd);", Connectie.connMEVO_ART);                                   

#region parameters
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@art", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@oms", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopoms.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@rem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopopmerk.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@artdk", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopnummerlev.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkooparttype.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@mag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopmagazijnloc.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@program", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopinternopmerk.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@eh1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopeenheid.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@lev", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopstandleveran.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ltd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkooplevertijd.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ink", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopbrutoprijs.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@kor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopkorting.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@sgr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopserievoorraad.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@eh2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopgebruikeh.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@ef", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.textinkoopehfactor.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@valuta", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopvaluta.Text;
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@crni", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.tekstinkoopcrni.Text;
#endregion
drART = slinkoopadd.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("Artikel opgeslagen!");
fillbox();
while (drART.Read())
{ }
slinkoopadd.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this?

```
slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@art", SqlDbType.VarChar);
slinkoopadd.Parameters["@art"].Value = this.artnr.SelectedValue;
```

I'm not sure you can pipe the call like that.

Comment: Why? This is the same as `slinkoopadd.Parameters.Add("@art", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.artnr.SelectedValue;` This won't effect anything.

Comment: I've had issues in the past with piping the call like that, as in Add did not return an object, just a boolean indicating success.

Comment: the parameters i have for this one are in the same format as i used them for all my other query's and they work without a problem atm

Answer (score 0):

```
drART = slinkoopadd.ExecuteReader();
```

You don't expect to *read* something. You want to insert, that is not a query:

```
var result = slinkoopadd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This is _of course_ true. But doesn't point the error OP have :)

Comment: it inserts either way as far as i know and i dont really want to change a thing that i know that works if it doesnt solve the problem. i want to solve the problem first and then i could look into that :)

Comment: @maam27 I guess we simply differ by process. I would not search for errors as long as I *know* something else is not in order.

Comment: if i wasnt sure that the executereader worked or not i would have changed it but i know it will work so i rather go with something i know i work then something i would have no clue about